# Javascript isn't executing when including html-template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Since I started using a html-templatefile for my navbar elements I haven't got one of my scripts to execute(I can execute it via the console). I have experimented with on-load-functions but even that didn't seem to work. My problem is that I understand to little of the execution order and if I'm somehow blocking my script. I don't get any error messages either and when the html-template isn't used (ie - the navbar structure is included with everything else in the same html-file) the page loads as it should. So something there is messing it up. And I can call it from the console as well.

(I have tried a variety of ways but nothing have really worked, other than including the template in the document and that I would like to avoid. This setup is one of many). I hope someone can see the errors I do on the spot. I have cut out som css aswell, for readability.

Edit: Threw js out the window, since ASP was found available. Solved it in about half an hour using asp.

Comment: There are `div` elements outside/before the `body` tag, is this intentional?

Comment: Your code is invalid. Put DOM elements in the body tag.

Comment: Yeah, your're right. In this case it isn't the problem (my real files have them in the right order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted but it turned out we had asp enabled on our server so when I switched to that I got it to work beautiful in about half an hour.

And it's a better way I suspect, in terms of best practice.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are trying to reference in the   `$("#pageContainerId").load("navbarTemplate.html");` is outside the body tag and most browsers will cut this out.
Try the following:

```
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'> 
            $(function(){
                $("#pageContainerId").load("navbarTemplate.html"); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>




<body id="bodyCanvas">
<div class="masthead">
    <div class="container">        

    </div>
</div>
<div class="container Override" id ="pageContainerId" >



</div>
    <script>
        Here goes code....
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also as the script is at the top the DOM may not be loaded at the time try the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#pageContainerId").load("navbarTemplate.html"); 
            });
```

Comment: Yeah they should :) I seem to have messed up the structure during my experimantation. That said, it isn't the problem here atleast. I still don't get any result from the js without calling it from the console.

Comment: Thx, I hoped that would help but alas it didn't. It still won't load. Added a function call I tried using to the original post, if it might highlight the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just place your DOM elements inside body tag. Always render script at the end of the body, and append async javascript files at document ready (or at least this is my view of things).

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <link href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>


    <body id="bodyCanvas">


    <div class="masthead">
        <div class="container">        

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container Override" id ="pageContainerId" >



    </div>
        <script>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> // create a local copy of jquery and other async javascript files you can load at $(document).ready(function(){ //here append async scripts like google maps });

        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'> 
            $(function(){
                $("#pageContainerId").load("navbarTemplate.html"); 
            });
        </script>
            Here goes code....
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have had the dom-elements inside the body tag before but when I have been experimenting I seem to have messed up the file. 

That said, that still won't do, it still don't execute the js (or, it might, but I don't get any results). If I call the script from the console, the chart and other things show up as the should. No error's either (other than a glyphicon error but that's unrelated)

Answer (score 0):

**DOM ELEMENT SHOULD INSIDE BODY TAG**

```
<body id="bodyCanvas">
        <div class="masthead">
    <div class="container">        

    </div>
</div>
<div class="container Override" id ="pageContainerId" >



</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yeah they should :) I seem to have messed up the structure during my experimantation. That said, it isn't the problem here atleast. I still don't get any result from the js without calling it from the console.